# search pandas dataframe for keywords in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

im trying to search through a csv file for keywords but right now I cant even find one string here is what I'm doing any solutions
I converted the csv to a pandas dataframe I would like to add a id=ndication to the dataframe like a check or running count

```
  import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('InventoryValue-byItem-6-25-22.csv')

df.apply(lambda columns: columns.astype(str).str.contains("VODKA").any(), axis=1)

df.to_csv('file_name.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends if you want to filter only in one column:

```
import pandas as pd

data={'number':np.random.uniform(0,20,size=5),'text1':["test VODKA","test","Nothing","Something","VODKA Orange"], 'text2':["no","VODKA sprite","yes","yes","no"] }
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

#If you are only looking in one column:
#cast the column as string...
df['text1'].astype(str)
print(df[df['text1'].astype(str).str.contains("VODKA",case=False)])
```

Result:

```
      number         text1 text2
0  17.505103    test VODKA    no
4  17.585175  VODKA Orange    no
```

Or in all columns:

```
import pandas as pd

data={'number':np.random.uniform(0,20,size=5),'text1':["test VODKA","test","Nothing","Something","VODKA Orange"], 'text2':["no","VODKA sprite","yes","yes","VODKA Orange"] }
df=pd.DataFrame(data)


#to look in all columns
dfFinal=pd.DataFrame()
for column in df.columns:
    dfTemp=df[df[column].astype(str).str.contains("VODKA",case=False)]
    dfFinal=dfFinal.append(dfTemp)

dfFinal.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
print(dfFinal)
```

Result:

```
      number         text1         text2
0   4.690792    test VODKA            no
4   8.835689  VODKA Orange  VODKA Orange
1  17.707329          test  VODKA sprite
```